# left join query running too long

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-10

I have two tables, `test1` and `test2`, and these tables have around 600M(70GB) and 10k(2MB) records, respectively. when I run a query with `left join` on `site_id`, it is taking too long, even though `site_id` has an index in both tables.`table1.rank` also indexed.

Added tables structure here [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d3dc576ec2b8b3283ed9017b5ec6e140)

`EXPLAIN` Query:

```
explain SELECT count(*) FROM test1 t1
   left join test2 t2 
   on t1.site_id =t2.site_id where rank=1;
```

Execution plan:

```
"  ->  Gather  (cost=273235.26..273235.77 rows=5 width=8)"
"        Workers Planned: 5"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=272235.26..272235.27 rows=1 width=8)"
"              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test t1  (cost=0.00..267015.64 rows=2087846 width=0)"
"                    Filter: (rank = 1)"
```

Execution plan with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=273235.78..273235.79 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=625.486..625.486 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=233204"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=273235.26..273235.77 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=624.638..700.069 rows=6 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 5"
"        Workers Launched: 5"
"        Buffers: shared hit=233204"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=272235.26..272235.27 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=436.761..436.762 rows=1 loops=6)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=233204"
"              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test1 t1  (cost=0.00..267015.64 rows=2087846 width=0) (actual time=0.014..336.926 rows=1739383 loops=6)"
"                    Filter: (rank = 1)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 514726"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=233204"
"Planning time: 0.120 ms"
"Execution time: 700.117 ms"
```

Execution plan with a `partition` on `test1`, `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

```
"Finalize Aggregate  (cost=233119.25..233119.26 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=999.316..999.316 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=179937"
"  ->  Gather  (cost=233118.73..233119.24 rows=5 width=8) (actual time=998.124..1054.495 rows=6 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 5"
"        Workers Launched: 5"
"        Buffers: shared hit=179937"
"        ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=232118.73..232118.74 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=796.767..796.768 rows=1 loops=6)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=179937"
"              ->  Result  (cost=0.00..226900.55 rows=2087269 width=0) (actual time=0.014..649.061 rows=1739383 loops=6)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=179937"
"                    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..206027.86 rows=2087269 width=6) (actual time=0.014..515.933 rows=1739383 loops=6)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=179937"
"                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on test1_p1 t1  (cost=0.00..206027.86 rows=2087269 width=6) (actual time=0.012..415.959 rows=1739383 loops=6)"
"                                Filter: (rank = 1)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=179937"
"Planning time: 0.254 ms"
"Execution time: 1054.547 ms"
```

Comment: The condition `rank = 1` returns about 80% of all rows, so the index won't be helpful. You could try a partial index: `create index on test1(the_primary_key_column) where rank = 1` to see if that triggers an index only scan that is faster.

Comment: I created a list partition on the table by `rank` in `1`, so both cases are the same right?

Comment: A list partition is something different than a partial index

Comment: No luck, created partial index still same behavior :(

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL optimizes the query so that the left join is completely ignored, so that doesn't factor in the question at all.

You didn't provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` results, but either you don't have an index on `test1.rank`, or PostgreSQL considers the condition not selective enough.

One thing you can try is to create an index on `test1.rank` and `VACUUM test1`, then perhaps you can get a faster index-only scan.

Comment: updated post with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` results and the `index `has on `test1.rank`. I mentioned in db<>fiddle. And also, I created `partition` test1.rank with the `list partition` but didn't see a big difference.

Comment: Thanks. So the condition is not selective at all. You can try for an index-only scan as detailed in my edited answer.

Comment: yes, I did run both `VACUUM test1` and also `VACUUM ANALYZE test1`, there is no improvements.

Comment: Try with `enable_seqscan = off`, see if you get an index-only scan and if that is faster.

Comment: seems, `seq scan` is better than `index scan`, ```Finalize Aggregate  (cost=315410.51..315410.52 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5554.103..5554.103 rows=1 loops=1)```. the final cost increased to nearly 30%.

Comment: Were there any "heap fetches" in the plan? If not, then the sequenctial scan that PostgreSQL picked is really the fastest way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109147/discussion-between-rj-n-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: There is nothing more to say about this...

Comment: I don't see any heep, pasted planer in chat.